# How to use stix2 font in PdfLaTex for documents with two languages Russian and English (with hyphenation)

Tags: hyphenation, stix, russian

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[OT1, OT2]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\usepackage{stix2}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=30mm, right=15mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{russian}
Пытаясь проскочить, крошечный баркас храбро поплыл к огромной барже. Но лодочник неудачно бросил бечеву и попал в ворот. Баркас повернулся на месте и остановился.

\selectlanguage{english}
A tiny launch, pulling heroically at a huge tow-barge, attempted to pass between; but the boatman shot nervily across her bow, and just as he was clear, unfortunately, caught a crab. This slewed the boat around and brought it to a stop.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `stix2` fonts support neither OT2 nor T2A. Also using `cp1251` is not the best way to type multilingual documents nowadays.

It's much better if you first convert your document to UTF-8 and then switch to T2A for Cyrillic text.

A good substitute for a Times-like font such as STIX2 is Tempora.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\usepackage{stix2}

\DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{T2A}{stix2}{Tempora-TLF}

\begin{document}

\pretolerance=0
\hyphenpenalty=-5000

Пытаясь проскочить, крошечный баркас храбро поплыл к огромной барже.
Но лодочник неудачно бросил бечеву и попал в ворот.
Баркас повернулся на месте и остановился.

\selectlanguage{english}
A tiny launch, pulling heroically at a huge tow-barge, attempted to
pass between; but the boatman shot nervily across her bow, and just
as he was clear, unfortunately, caught a crab. This slewed the boat
around and brought it to a stop.

\end{document}
```

The strange settings before the Russian text are just to make hyphenation more desirable, in order to show that it's applied correctly.

[image]