# stix2 not work with Russian language

Tags: babel, russian, stix2

I am trying to use the `stix2` package in together with the Russian language. But when I enable Russian language support, the font of the plain text becomes CM instead of STIX.

Work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{stix2}

\begin{document}
text $math$
\end{document}
```

Not work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{stix2}

\begin{document}
text $math$
\end{document}
```

If I add the `OT2` encoding at the same time, the word `text` will turn into the word `тешт`, typed in STIX font:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1, T2A, OT2]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{stix2}

\begin{document}
text $math$
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to use `stix2` together with the Russian language and if so, how?
All I could find on the internet is [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/532213/171124), which suggests using a third-party font. I would like to do with the stix font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The STIX2 fonts don't support the T2A encoding, so you want to replace the text font with one that does and is Times-compatible.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{stix2}
\usepackage{tempora}% replace the text font

\begin{document}

text $a+b=2$ русский язык

\end{document}
```

[image]